# Why did my app keep crashing on debug mode and also the released version is crashing on startup in flutter?

Tags: flutter, build, crash, startup

I released the app earlier and then it couldn't run now, I can't run it in debug or release versions, I just completed the setup of publishing the app on play store and then when I visited my code to make some changes it keeps on crashing.
Below is my app level build.gradle file, -

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {

    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the 
local.properties file.")
}
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

android {
 
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
    }
    buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}


dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I am new as developer, published first time.
I did keyStore setup, signed my app and completed the whole publishing process and then it is happening,
I want to get rid of this situation, please comment the appropriate answer.

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH52e.jpg

Comment: Can you post the crash here?

Comment: In the VS code or in android studio, whenever I run the process doesn't go further installing app and in the android device it tries to start and the splash screen appears and then the app closes, but in the vs code the installing app thing keep on showing and the app never start!

Comment: @ClaudioRedi what should I post?